# Obtaining like/dislike count from entries in a YouTube channel's uploads feed

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to retrieve the amount of likes and dislikes in a channel feeds. But got only the rating of each video. Is there any way to get this information from likes and dislikes?

My code:

```
// set feed URL
$feedURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads";

// read feed into SimpleXML object
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

// get <gd:rating> node for video ratings
$gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');

foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {

      if ($gd->rating) {
        $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();        
        $rating = $attrs['average'];                
      }

      /*
       * does not work
       *
        $yt = $entry->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
        $attrs = $yt->rating->attributes();
        $dislikes = $attrs['numDislikes'];
        $likes = $attrs['numLikes'];
      */

}
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `v=2` parameter to specify that you want v2 of the Data API, which supports likes/dislikes.

Additionally, you might find things easier if you add in `alt=jsonc` since you could then work with JSON rather than XML. E.g. http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc